# Uninstalled nvidia driver on the external server - cant connect now

Tags: server, nvidia, graphics, ssh, cuda

On an external server with Ubuntu 14.04 I have CUDA8 running on Tesla K40. Never had a problem for over 9 months. Last night something happened to nvidia driver 378: nvidia-smi and nvidia-detector reported that there's no nvidia driver installed (just `sudo apt-get nvidia-378` reported that it is indeed installed). I purged the drivers intending to reinstall them, but something went wrong. I rebooted and now, when I try logging to the server from my computer, I get the same message over and over again:

```
/usr/bin/mosh: Could not connect to [SERVER ADDRESS]: No route to host
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
/usr/bin/mosh: Did not find remote IP address (is SSH ProxyCommand disabled?).
```

SSH reports just the first line. What should I do? Our IT people won't be able to do anything until Monday, and I have tonnes of work to do

Comment: Looks like "them" will have to wait till Monday.

Comment: so there's no way I can boot to a server without nvidia driver?

Comment: Do you mean 'log into the server'? I don't know what "boot to a server" means, not to mention if you can or can't do it. It is clear that you need to get to the server and investigate what went wrong. Perhaps another reboot will solve the problem, but there is no magic word that reboots any server remotely, in case that was something you were looking for.

Comment: If the boot process of the remote machine reach to load `ssh-server` service should be enough to connect to it. Does respond to ping? then, does `nc IP PORT` work? Try that before using mosh, which need an UDP port (_Mosh will log the user in via SSH, then start a connection [on a UDP port](https://mosh.org/#usage) between 60000 and 61000._). If everything works with ssh then try `mosh --ssh="ssh -p SSHPORT"  username@serverip`.